# Вывод консоли в richtextbox C# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

Я пытаюсь сделать вывод консоли в `RichTextBox`.
Вот мой код:

```
public void Run()
{
    Process myProcess = new Process();
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"start.bat";
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    myProcess.OutputDataReceived += proc_OutputDataReceived;
    myProcess.Start();
    myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
}

public void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   this.Invoke(new Action(() => 
   richTextBoxConsole.Text += (e.Data + Environment.NewLine)));
}
```

Но в `RichTextBox` отображается только первая строчка из консоли. А Надо чтоб отображались все строчки в режиме реального времени. Где ошибка?

Comment: А у вас все консольные сообщения идут через "myProcess.OutputDataReceived" ?

Comment: да, идут все консольные сообщения

Comment: По логике все правильно. Попробуйте сделать статическую консоль на richTextBox, так же попробуйте дополнительно консольные сообщения сохранять в строку и вызывать текстовую консольку прямо.

Comment: Приведенный код рабочий, все отлично выводится. Воспроизвести проблему не удалось. Тестировал  в контролах WinForms. Скорее всего нужно проверять батник, на предмет его выводв при запуске в стандартной консоли без редиректа. Ну и кодировка тут не учтена, так что будут кракозяблы при выводе.

Comment: лучше не используйте простую конкатенацию `richTextBoxConsole.Text +=`  
Используйте `richTextBoxConsole.AppendText()`

Comment: Посмотрите http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599557/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-7z/599642#599642

Answer (score 1):

в оф документации майкрсофт есть почти что готовое решение

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx

подписаться на соответующее событие и просто дублирвать текст на даном событии в нужное поле