# Как получить список файлов архива 7z?

Tags: c#, 7z, archive

7z l my.zip > my.txt

Это приводит к ошибке:

`>` log.txt

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.Exception" в
>   file_backup.exe
>
> Дополнительные сведения: sevenzip.addtoarchive: Ошибка в командной
>   строке

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.FileName = archiver;
                startInfo.Arguments = " l ";
                startInfo.Arguments += "\"" + archiveName+ "\"";

                startInfo.Arguments += " > " +  "log.txt";

                startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                int sevenZipExitCode = 0;
                using (Process sevenZip = Process.Start(startInfo))
```

Comment: Рискну предположить что 7z ничего не знает об опции командной строки ">". Попробуйте запускать cmd.exe с командой на запуск 7Z

Comment: А ещё у ProcessStartInfo есть такой мембер, как RedirectStandardOutput.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов команда правильная, НО: 7z по умолчанию не обнаруживается командной строкой, поэтому нужен полный путь к нему или явно прописать его  переменной окружения PATH; имена архива и целевого файла также должны быть с указанием полного пути и должны быть в наличии все необходимые права.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов вы оказались отчасти правы, для консоли команда верная, только там не одна а две команды, вторая для самой консоли и ее нужно писать вручную. Ответ дополнил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Проверьте, что путь к `7z.exe` прописан в переменной окружения `PATH`, без этого даже из командной строки вы будете получать ошибку, или укажите путь явно в команде.
2. Проверьте, что у пользователя, от имени которого запускается программа достаточно прав на чтение архива и запись файла в соответствующую папку.
3. Укажите пути к файлам явно и полностью. Я не любитель абсолютных путей, но с этого стоит начать, т.к. относительные пути иногда ведут не туда, куда вы предполагаете. Если вариант с полными путями сработает, можно начинать искать ошибки в относительных путях.
4. Для процесса можно, а часто нужно, явно задать рабочую директорию, тогда проблем с относительными путями будет на порядок меньше.

---

Нашел в чем проблема с вашим кодом, но это не отменяет всего описанного выше.

Команда `7z l my.zip > my.txt` для CMD или PowerShell абсолютно верная, но ее нельзя просто засунуть в аргументы запуска процесса, т.к. по сути в этой записи не одна а две команды: команда для архиватора `7z l my.zip` - вывести список файлов и команда для консоли `> my.txt` - перенаправить вывод в файл.

Таким образом нам нужно в коде реализовать тоже самое, т.е. запустить процесс процесс для архиватора, с его параметрами и перенаправить вывод в файл.

Сделать это можно так:

```
static void Main()
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = @"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe",
        Arguments = @"l <путь к архиву>\my.zip",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };
    using (Process sevenZip = new Process())
    {
        sevenZip.StartInfo = startInfo;
        sevenZip.OutputDataReceived += proc_OutputDataReceived;
        sevenZip.Start();
        sevenZip.BeginOutputReadLine();
        sevenZip.WaitForExit();
    }
}
private static void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var wr = File.AppendText(@"<путь к файлу>\log.txt"))
        wr.WriteLine(e.Data);
}
```