# Как можно извлечь вывод любого консольного приложения

Tags: c#, консоль, terminal

Я запускаю консольное приложение из кода C# с помощью `Process.Start("**","**")`. Мне нужно узнать то, что вывелось в окно этого приложения. Как Вам, скорее всего известно, перенаправление потоков ( `>` ) в данном случае не работает. Как мне это осуществить?

Comment: Переводя на технический язык, вы хотите получить stdout и stderr программно запущенного процесса.

Comment: Дубль? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/599557/198316

Answer (score 2):

```
Process myprocess = new Process();
myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = "rm";
myprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-rf /";
myprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
myprocess.Start();    

Console.WriteLine(myprocess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

myprocess.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Ну вы бы всё же какой-то более гуманистический пример придумали, что ли :)

Comment: Не подскажите, с чем может быть связано исключение System.InvalidOperationException - Поток StandardOut не был перенаправлен или процесс еще не был запущен?