# Вывод информации о выполнении в PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

Добрый день. Имеется файл написанный на C#, например 'app.cs'. Необходимо скомпилировать этот файл через приложение в C#. Если компилятор выдаст выдаст ошибки компиляции, то необходимо перенаправить вывод в текстовый файл. Проблема такова, что из C# выполняется скрипт PowerShell в котором и запускается сам компилятор. Не совсем понимаю PowerShell, поэтому и обращаюсь к сообществу. Далее приведу код:

- Код скрипта PowerShell

> @"Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\csc.exe'
>   -ArgumentList 'app.cs' -Wait -NoNewWindow | Out-File -FilePath log.txt"

- Код C#

  ```
  string script = ... // см. выше 
  Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
  runspace.Open();
  Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
  pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script);   
  Collection<PSObject> result = pipeline.Invoke();
  runspace.Close();
  ```

p.s. Переменная result так же пустая.

Comment: [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599642/198316) я уже отвечал на подобное для CMD. В вашем случае " | Out-File -FilePath log.txt" - перенаправление в файл средствами PowerShell, попробуйте адаптировать решение из того ответа, если не разберетесь сами, напишу сюда отдельно для PowerShell

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/78f4aasd.aspx это отправная точка для изучения компиляции из командной строки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо @rdorn. Необходимо было переопределить вывод. Ответ на PowerShell

```
$objectStartInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo -Property @{
    "FileName" = "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\csc.exe"
    "Arguments" = "p1.cs"
    "UseShellExecute" = $false
    "RedirectStandardOutput" = $true
}

$processObject = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$processObject.StartInfo = $objectStartInfo
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $processObject -EventName OutputDataReceived -action{
    $Event.SourceEventArgs.Data >> log.txt
}

$processObject.Start()
$processObject.BeginOutputReadLine()
```

Comment: У вас получился ну прям совсем C#-way. PowerShell way выглядел бы примерно так: `Start-Process -FilePath 'csc.exe' -ArgumentList 'app.cs' -RedirectStandardOutput 'output.log' -RedirectStandardError 'error.log'`.

Comment: @n01d, я потом и вовсе переписал через API компилятора