# Как узнать, что в домашнюю сеть подключились новые клиенты?

Tags: c#, сеть, администрирование

Есть роутер, мой ПК подключен к нему напрямую через LAN.

Хочу получить список клиентов программным образом.

Пробовал использовать такой метод:

```
 DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT:");
        foreach (DirectoryEntry computers in root.Children)
        {
            foreach (DirectoryEntry computer in computers.Children)
            {
                if (computer.Name != "Schema")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(computer.Name); 
                }
            }
        }
```

Но получаю только список пк, в то время, как антивирус ESET каким-то образом узнает, что к сети подключилось новое Android устройство.

Собственно вопрос, как получить список устройств локальной сети?

Comment: Посмотри тут, может подойдет http://www.cyberforum.ru/post1806738.html, сам не проверял, вопрос на стыке с администрированием, так что пару нужных меток добавлю к вопросу

Comment: Еще есть встроенная команда `net view`, она показывает текущие устройства в сети. Можно перенаправить вывод и вызвад с нужными ключами.

Comment: @rdorn, хм... Без параметров он все равно не выводит мобильные устройства.

Comment: A `arp -a` что выводит?

Comment: @rdorn, а вот это выводит список из статичесих и динамических IP. Как я понял, динамика как раз то, что подключено по WiFi, так как кол-во совпадает и маки похожи на то, что показывает роутер.

Comment: Беда в том, что когда устройство подключается. оно о себе не обязано сообщать. Но с динамическими адресами проще, устройство вынуждено получить адрес для работы, поэтому бродкастит что-то типа "Кто я? Где я?" и выданный адрес попадает в arp. Можно попробовать это использовать, но все равно вызывать команду arp придется периодически руками

Comment: Ключевое слово для гугления: UPnP (Universal Plug and Play). Винда находит устройства в сети именно через него.

Comment: @rdorn ^^ // cc

Comment: @PavelMayorov не совсем, UPnP без пинка не работает и процесс обнаружения довольно долгий. Как дополнение к ARP бесспорно удобная штука, но базовое обнаружение через ARP на порядок быстрее. Плюс ARP работает независимо от криворукости и/или паранойи администратора сети.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле вопрос не так прост, как может показаться. Существует низкоуровневое решение, но применительно к .NET это перебор, к тому же, даже такое решение не гарантирует 100% обнаружение нового хоста. Мне удалось найти старую, но актуальную [статью с описанием принципов работы ARP](http://samlit.net/lessons/informatika/tcp_ip/tcp04.html), с помощью которого и попытаемся решить обозначенную проблему. А теперь по порядку.

Просто узнать о том, что устройство подключилось или отключилось от сети не получится, потому что устройство может, **но не обязано** сообщать всем о своем присутствии в сети. Протокол ARP относится к протоколам канального уровня в модели OSI и выполняет функции соспоставления физических (MAC) и логических (IP) адресов.

В некоторых реализациях предусмотрен, так называемый, "беспричинный" ARP (gratuitous ARP). Он проявляется, когда хост посылает ARP запрос, основываясь на собственном IP адресе. Обычно это делается, когда интерфейс конфигурируется во время загрузки. Этот запрос является широковещательным, поэтому все хосты одной сети добавляют запись в ARP-кэш и узнают о новом участнике. Вроде бы то что нужно, но стандарты не обязывают к реализации данного функционала.

Таким образом, чтобы получить список всех хостов сети, можно просмотреть ARP-кэш, получить из него список IP- и MAC-адресов, ну а дальше уже по известным адресам выяснять что это за хост тем или иным способом (не рассматривается в рамках данного вопроса).

Получить содержимое ARP-кэша можно консольной командой `arp -a`, перенаправив вывод в команды в свою программу ([рабочий пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599642/198316))

Для отслеживания подключения новых устройств нужно периодически опрашивать ARP-кэш и сравнивать результаты с полученными ранее. Других вариантов без глубокого копания в драйверах сетевой карты нет, т.к. это канальный уровень. На более высоких сетевых уровнях OSI данная задача может быть решена только кооперативно, а значит не может быть решена для произвольных устройств.

**UPD:** Технология UPnP, упомянутая [@Pavel Mayorov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178779/pavel-mayorov) относится к кооперативным, т.е. устройство должно ее поддерживать, чтобы другое устройство могло его обнаружить таким способом и не смотря на упоминание Universal в аббревиатуре, на самом деле поддерживается не всеми и не всегда, а иногда просто отключается в целях безопасности.

---

**Ограничения**

У ARP-кэша довольно большие таймауты обновления, т.к. протокол создавался военными для применения на радиоканалах, где временная потеря связи обычное явление. Поэтому кэш может содержать записи о давно отключенных хостах.

Как говорилось выше, не все реализуют и используют "беспричинный" ARP (gratuitous ARP), поэтому нельзя считать, что если в кэше нет записи, то устройство не подключено, оно могло просто еще не сообщить о себе, но сообщит при первой попытке обратиться к любому другому участнику сети, включая несуществующих.