# Вывод одной консольки в другую

Tags: c#, консоль

Есть два консольных приложения, одно из которых написано на другом языке и т. д.
Второе приложение - консольное приложение в C#, которое при запуске должно вызывать первое и перехватывать весь его вывод в себя. Каким бы глупым не был вопрос, но как это сделать?

Comment: посмотрите тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599642/198316. В о второй половине ответа есть код который вам нужен

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне нужно получать вывод из программы тогда, когда она что то выводит, потому что первая программа - компиляторы уровней для квакоподобного движка

Comment: замените код в `proc_OutputDataReceived` на нужную вам обработку вывода и пользуйтесь результатами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

Оказалось что я неправильно расставил булевы переменные, если стартовать процесс с такими параметрами, все будет работать