# Как получить результат компиляции?

Tags: c#, .net, компиляция

Делаю ide для языка C# на WinForms. При запуске отправляю файлу csc.exe исходники и путь где должен лежать будущий exe. Все работает, но как мне перехватить ошибку при неудачной компиляции?

Код того как я компилирую:

```
new Process() {
    StartInfo = {
        FileName=@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe",
        Arguments=@"-out:" + SelectedFile.FullName + @".exe " + SelectedFile.FullName
    }
}.Start();
```

код того как запускаю:

```
Process.Start(new DirectoryInfo(PathToFolderWithFiles).GetFiles(@"*.exe")
        .Where(a => a.Name.Split('.')[0] == SelectedFile.Name.Split('.')[0])
        .Single().FullName);
```

При неуспешной компиляции не создается файл exe. Хотелось бы получить источник ошибки.

Comment: перехватить консольный вывод от csc.exe и вывести в своей программе. Вот тут уже решали похожую проблему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599642/198316

Comment: У csc.exe есть параметр `/errorlog:<file>` - Specify a file to log all compiler and analyzer diagnostics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нет необходимости вызывать компилятор напрямую, для этого есть встроенный API (*System.CodeDom.Compiler*). Ошибки можно получить через свойство *CompilerResults.Errors*:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

namespace WindowsFormsTest1
{    
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {        

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();                   
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            string filepath = "c:\\test\\Hello.cs";
            var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" }, "c:\\test\\Hello.exe", true);
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;

            CompilerResults results = csc.CompileAssemblyFromFile(parameters, new string[]{filepath});
            if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Errors: " + Environment.NewLine;

                foreach (var err in results.Errors)
                {
                    textBox1.Text += err.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                return;
            }
            else MessageBox.Show("Компиляция завершена успешно!");

        }      
    }        

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно в [`Console.SetOut`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.setout(v=vs.110).aspx) задать новый поток вывода и читать его в своей программе, анализируя вывод консоли.

Правда все таки лучше использовать API, как советуют ниже.