# Как получить текст из консольного приложения (ListDLLs)

Tags: c#, cmd, bat

ListDLLs выдаёт текст в консоль при правильных аргументах.

А как перенести этот текст в C# чтобы потом с ним работать?

Comment: В c# есть полезный класс `Process`, воспользуйтесь им. Все тоже самое что делает эта утилита можно написать с его помощью.

Comment: Где-то тут я отвечал на такой же вопрос про 7zip. Нужно перенаправить поток вывода и читать оттуда все что возвращает приложение

Comment: [нашел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599642/198316), адаптировать под другую программу элементарно. Ну если я правильно понял что именно вам нужно.