# Не могу получить от ProcessStartInfo вывод когда "вызываю" цикличискую программу

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, потоки-данных

Не могу получить от ProcessStartInfo   вывод когда  "вызываю" цикличискую программу. Не получается ПроцессСтартом получить вывод результата.

Потоком ProcessStartInfo хочу получить вывод как в примере:

```
dima@komp:~/mita/TCP_IP$ ping www.ya.ru
PING ya.ru (87.250.250.242) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=13.2 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=12.6 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=16.1 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=12.7 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=5 ttl=52 time=12.6 ms
^C64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=6 ttl=52 time=17.6 ms
^Z
[2]+  Остановлен    ping www.ya.ru
dima@komp:~/mita/TCP_IP$
```

Для этого написал такую программку :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

    public class Test
    {
      public static void Main()
      {
        // создаем процесс cmd.exe с параметрами "ipconfig /all"
        //ProcessStartInfo psiOpt = new ProcessStartInfo("ifconfig");
        ProcessStartInfo psiOpt = new ProcessStartInfo("ping"); // не работает но ошибку не даёт
        //ProcessStartInfo psiOpt = new ProcessStartInfo("mono"); 
        // скрываем окно запущенного процесса
        psiOpt.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        // передаём аргументы 
        psiOpt.Arguments = "www.ya.ru";// не работает но ошибку не даёт
        //psiOpt.Arguments = "tehn.exe";
        // настраиваем процесс
        psiOpt.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psiOpt.UseShellExecute = false;
        psiOpt.CreateNoWindow = true;
        // запускаем процесс
        Process procCommand = Process.Start(psiOpt);
        for (; ; )
        {
            // получаем ответ запущенного процесса
            StreamReader srIncoming = procCommand.StandardOutput;
            // выводим результат
            Console.WriteLine(srIncoming.ReadToEnd());
        }
            // закрываем процесс
        procCommand.WaitForExit();
        // вводим одну клавишу и закрываем программу 
        Console.ReadKey();
      }
    }
```

Но увы результат работы программы меня совершенно не устроил :

```
dima@komp:~/mita/TCP_IP$ mcs lovla_terminal3.cs 
lovla_terminal3.cs(32,9): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected
Compilation succeeded - 1 warning(s)
dima@komp:~/mita/TCP_IP$ mono lovla_terminal3.exe 
zx
xz
cxzc
^C
dima@komp:~/mita/TCP_IP$
```

---

Как я понял, я **упускаю** важный момент вывода потока `StreamReader-а` потому как я заметил поток `ProcessStartInfo` выводит после исполнения вызванной программы, для решения этой проблеммы я добавил вечный цикл `for(;;)`. Увы это не дало результата.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45540375/5045688

Comment: Может проще использовать [Ping Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599642/198316) я описывал как перехватить консольный вывод другой программы и писать его в файл, легко модифицируется под вывод в консоль вашей программы. И ни каких бесконечных циклов.

Comment: В .NET Framework под Windows все отлично работает, выводит в консоль результат пинга. Либо баг моно, либо ping в linux работает по другому (не генерирует конец потока, поэтому ReadToEnd и висит бесконечно). Попробуйте считывать построчно вместо ReadToEnd.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight а как считывать построчно ???

Comment: В цикле вызывать ReadLine, пока оно не вернет null. Или как в примере от rdorn, воспользоваться событием DataReceived.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight у вы я так не пойму мне на уровне примера надо . А то как то очень сложно

Comment: @rdorn можете пожалуйста прокомментировать мой ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @rdorn

Я адаптировал ваш [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599557/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-7z/599642#599642) к моему вопросу

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

    public class Test
    {
      public static void Main()
      {
        // оформляем процесс 
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "ping", // имя запускаемого процесса
            Arguments = "www.ya.ru", // аргументы процесса
            // настройки что именно от процесса " получать "
            RedirectStandardOutput = true, 
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };
        // Какая то неизвестная для меня конструкция , увы так и не понял 
        // как она работает, по этому расписал как вижу :3 
        using (Process sevenZip = new Process())
        {
            // Думаю что соразмерно  Process sevenZip = Process.Start(startInfo);
            sevenZip.StartInfo = startInfo;
            // Настраиваем приём данных (сообщений) от запущенного процесса 
            // совершенно непонятно как это работает
            // ибо OutputDataReceived это System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler 
            // да и символ += сложно (в общем не "функциональное погромирование")
            sevenZip.OutputDataReceived += proc_OutputDataReceived;
            // запускаем процесс
            sevenZip.Start();
            //получаем ответ запущенного процесса
            sevenZip.BeginOutputReadLine();
            // закрываем процесс
            sevenZip.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
    private static void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Вывод в консоль принятых аргументов
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        // также пишем полученные данные в лог файл 
        using (var wr = File.AppendText("log.txt"))
            wr.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }
}
```

Вот вывод :

```
dima@komp:~/mita/TCP_IP$ mcs lovla_terminal4.cs 
dima@komp:~/mita/TCP_IP$ mono lovla_terminal4.exe 
PING ya.ru (87.250.250.242) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=12.3 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=13.6 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=12.6 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=12.7 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=5 ttl=52 time=14.0 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=6 ttl=52 time=12.5 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=7 ttl=52 time=12.6 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=8 ttl=52 time=12.5 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=9 ttl=52 time=13.7 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=10 ttl=52 time=12.6 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=11 ttl=52 time=15.7 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=12 ttl=52 time=12.6 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=13 ttl=52 time=12.6 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=14 ttl=52 time=16.8 ms
^Z
[1]+  Остановлен    mono lovla_terminal4.exe
dima@komp:~/mita/TCP_IP$
```

---

**Но увы так и не понял в истинном смысле как это работает ;_;**

Comment: Все правильно. Неизвестная конструкция - это очистка ресурсов (после выхода из блока using будет автоматически вызвано Process.Dispose). Оператор += в данном случае это присвоение обработчика события. Метод proc_OutputDataReceived может быть неявно преобразован в тип делегата DataReceivedEventHandler. Делегат "приплюсовывется" к многоадресному делегату, который под капотом у события OutputDataReceived, поэтому Process будет вызывать ваш метод при каждом событии получения данных.

Comment: тут все построено не на ручном вычитывании данных, а на прослушивании события получения данных, что позволяет не блокировать выполнение другого, не менее полезного кода, например ваша программа может запустить и слушать несколько консольных приложений и вести сводный лог. В целом все поняли правильно. Но думаю вам стоит разобраться с делегатами и событиями, а также заглянуть в документацию по using, будет как минимум не вредно.