# C#.Запуск внешнего консольного приложения с сохранением его вывода в listbox

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, как запустить консольное приложение с последующей записью его вывода в listbox. Я хочу сделать программу которая будет запускать tor Expert Bundle она запускается консолью в котором отображается лог подключения к сети tor,этот лог обновляется каждую секунду до подключения к сети и выглядит так:

```html
Nov 12 14:19:07.686 [notice] Tor 0.4.4.5 (git-24e808e946e741d0) running on Windows 7 with Libevent 2.1.11-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1g, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma N/A, and Libzstd N/A.
Nov 12 14:19:07.690 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Nov 12 14:19:07.713 [notice] Configuration file "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\tor\torrc" not present, using reasonable defaults.
Nov 12 14:19:07.717 [warn] Path for GeoIPFile (<default>) is relative and will resolve to C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TorController\TorController\bin\Debug\Tor\<default>. Is this what you wanted?
Nov 12 14:19:07.717 [warn] Path for GeoIPv6File (<default>) is relative and will resolve to C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TorController\TorController\bin\Debug\Tor\<default>. Is this what you wanted?
Nov 12 14:19:07.728 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Nov 12 14:19:07.728 [notice] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Nov 12 14:19:07.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0% (starting): Starting
Nov 12 14:19:12.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "default"
Nov 12 14:19:14.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay
Nov 12 14:19:14.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay
Nov 12 14:19:14.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay
Nov 12 14:19:14.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 15% (handshake_done): Handshake with a relay done
Nov 12 14:19:14.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 75% (enough_dirinfo): Loaded enough directory info to build circuits
Nov 12 14:19:14.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90% (ap_handshake_done): Handshake finished with a relay to build circuits
Nov 12 14:19:14.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 95% (circuit_create): Establishing a Tor circuit
Nov 12 14:19:14.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100% (done): Done
```

Мне нужно чтобы когда я нажал в программе на кнопку подключиться к сети tor то в listbox выводился и синхронно построчно этот лог.Буду очень рад если напишите код.

Comment: почитайте здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output

Comment: да и у нас обсуждалось: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1114573/213987 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599642/198316

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу получить от ProcessStartInfo вывод когда "вызываю" цикличискую программу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1114573/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82-processstartinfo-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83)

Comment: Готовый пример, правда с `TextBox`, но суть не особо меняется https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1086544/373567

Comment: Спасибо всем!!!!