# Получение данных из cmd при запуске скрипта python в приложении c#

Tags: c#, python-3.x

Всем доброго дня!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получать данные данные из командной строки при запуске ее из приложения с#.
Проблема в том, что результаты выполнения появляются **по завершении работы скрипта**, мне же нужно получать данные из cmd по ходу выполнения программы. Запускаю скрипт python. Скрипт выполняется в отдельном потоке.

Возможно можно сделать это как-то проще, но я нашел только такое решение.

Код такой:

```
 private Task consoleTask;
        private CancellationTokenSource consoleToken;

        private void RunConsoleCommand(string command)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var process = new Process()
                {
                    StartInfo =
                        {
                            CreateNoWindow = true,
                            UseShellExecute = false,
                            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                            StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866),
                            Arguments = "/c " + command,
                            FileName = "cmd.exe"
                        }
                })
                {
                    // Процесс еще не стартовал, просто выходим из функции...
                    if (consoleToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;

                    process.Start();

                    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                    {
                        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            if (consoleToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                            {
                                // Если функцию отменили принудительно, убиваем процесс.
                                process.Kill();
                                return;
                            }

                            var text = reader.ReadLine();
                            this.AppendLine(text);
                            Thread.Sleep(1);
                        }
                    }

                    // Если вывод закончился, ждем завершения процесса.
                    process.WaitForExit();
                } // Закрываем хендл
            }
            finally
            {
                this.EnableRun();
            }
        }

        private delegate void AppendLineDelegate(string text);

        private void AppendLine(string text)
        {
            if (!this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText(text + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            else
            {
                // На всякий случай, делаем вызов отложенным...
                this.BeginInvoke(new AppendLineDelegate(this.AppendLine), new object[] { text });
            }
        }

        private delegate void EnableRunDelegate();

        private void EnableRun()
        {
            if (!this.InvokeRequired)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                // Чтобы не войти в дедлок с ГУИ потоком, делаем вызов отложенным.
                this.BeginInvoke(new EnableRunDelegate(this.EnableRun));
            }
        }

        private void OnClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Просим поток завершиться.
            consoleToken.Cancel();
            // И даем ему возможность завершиться.
            consoleTask.Wait();
        }

        private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string command = "python C:\\test.py";

            consoleToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
            consoleTask = new Task(() => RunConsoleCommand(command), consoleToken.Token);
            consoleTask.Start();
        }
```

При попытке сделать тоже самое немного иначе получаю точно такой же результат - строка появляется в label1 только по завершении работы скрипта python.

```
 private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Calling Python...";
            this.Refresh();
            Tuple<String, String> python = GoPython(@"C:\test.py");
            label1.Text = python.Item1; // Show result.
            if (python.Item2.Length > 0) MessageBox.Show("Sorry, there was an error:" + Environment.NewLine + python.Item2);
        }

        public Tuple<String, String> GoPython(string pythonFile, string moreArgs = "")
        {
            ProcessStartInfo PSI = new ProcessStartInfo();
            PSI.FileName = "py.exe";
            PSI.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" {1}", pythonFile, moreArgs);
            PSI.CreateNoWindow = true;
            PSI.UseShellExecute = false;
            PSI.RedirectStandardError = true;
            PSI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            using (Process process = Process.Start(PSI))
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                string stderr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); // Error(s)!!
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); // What we want.
                return new Tuple<String, String>(result, stderr);
            }
        }
```

Comment: через события выходного потока https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599642/198316. Получаете все а онлайне. В примере перенаправление в файл, но вы можете выводить данные куда угодно, просто измените обработчик события.

Comment: Gypnofrog а что умеет такого Python с чем не может справится C#?

Comment: Когда проект уже написан на python и последнее, что осталось сделать - это передать данные в c# вопрос сам собой отпадает

Comment: @rdorn - не подскажите, как конкретно это сделать - вывести в label или textBox?

Comment: Вы в вашем коде это вроде уже делаете, ну так перенесите этот фрагмент в обработчик события Process.OutputDataReceived, в чем проблема то? Или уже попробовали и что-то не получилось? Тогда что именно не получилось и как пробовали?

Comment: @rdorn сделал как Вы сказали. проблема та же самая - вижу текст только после завершения работы скрипта. возможно это связано с тем, что cmd запускается в том же потоке, что и основное приложение

Comment: cmd запускается в отдельном процессе, так что это не влияет, а вот проверить запускаемый скрипт на предмет, в какой момент он выводит данные стоит. Попробуйте запустить `ping <куда угодно> -t` и посмотреть как будет происходить вывод. Если что, он не завершится пока его не убьешь с такими параметрами, так что процесс в какой-то момент надо будет убить в вашем коде или диспетчере.

Comment: просто если сам скрипт отдает вывод только в конце выполнения, даже если он огромен и кажется, что выводится постепенно, то вы с этим ни чего не сделаете без изменения скрипта

Comment: ну и если скрипт использует errorstream, то его тоже нужно перехватить аналогичным образом, если он вам конечно нужен

Comment: @rdorn скрипт не имеет конца и работает бесконечно. если запустить скрипт из cmd, то по ходу выполнения скрипта я вижу весь лог. Если же я запускаю скрипт из c# то вижу все логи, только при принудительном завершении скрипта. при запуске cmd из c# сама форма зависает, поэтому решил запускать cmd в отдельном потоке - помогло, форма не виснет, но логи скрипта  получаю так же после принудительного его завершения.

Comment: @rdorn попробую описать задачу чуть подробнее, может это поможет. необходимо запустить скрипт python из приложения c#, при этом форма не должна повисать. логику работы скрипта опишу условно - открыть браузер, зайти на сайт, написать лог с cmd, зайти на следующий сайт и т.д. логику описал ооооочень условно, но для понимания норм. скрипт делает это и пишет логи в cmd в реальном времени. логи выводятся в cmd обычным "print". при использовании кода, описанного выше c# все логи выводятся сразу только после принудительного завершения скрипта(закрытия браузера). во время работы логов нет

Comment: а вы собственный кусок с чтением из потока выпилить не забыли? Скорее всего на нем и висите, а он не нужен при обработке через события потока.

Comment: @rdorn не забыл, этого куска кода там нет. я уже подумал, что проблема в моём скрипте python, поэтому создал новый скрипт python с простым кодом: вывести сообщение, задержка 3 секунды и всё это в бесконечном цикле. пробую запустить его через c# и ничего. ни один из 3-х методов ничего не выводит. значит проблема общая для любого пайтоновского скрипта

Comment: Понятия не имею как у вам удалось заморозить интерфейс, хотя и догадываюсь. Ответ смотрите внимательно. Ни чего больше с запущенным процессом делать не надо, и запускать его из другого потока тоже не надо. А после этого вычищайте в своем коде всякую самодеятельность вроде WaitForExit, ReadToEnd и т.д. и т.п.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рабочий пример с бесконечным пингом. На всякий случай добавил демонстрацию перенаправления потока ошибок. Все построено на событиях потока, окно не блокируется.

Только учтите, что ни `TextBox`, ни `Label`, не способен адекватно обрабатывать большие объемы текста и добавление каждой следующей строки будет становиться медленнее, потому что при изменении текста он перерисовывает текст полностью, независимо от того, какой фрагмент реально отображается, а какой нет, хотя первое время это не заметно. Сколько кб|Мб текста он может съесть без заметного проседания производительности не проверял.

- Нет, это не лечится.
- Замена на `RichTextBox` поможет не надолго.

Реально помочь может только собственная или сторонняя реализация аналогичного контрола с поддержкой виртуализации отображаемого текста.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Process proc = null;
    private TextBox tb = new TextBox();

    public Form1()
    {
        var btn = new Button() { Text = "Ping -t" };
        Controls.Add(btn);
        btn.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        btn.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (proc != null) return;
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = @"ping",
                Arguments = @"8.8.8.8 -t",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };
            proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
            proc.OutputDataReceived += Proc_DataReceived;
            proc.ErrorDataReceived += Proc_DataReceived;
            proc.Start();
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        };
        Controls.Add(tb);
        tb.Multiline = true;
        tb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    private void Proc_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        tb.Invoke((Action)(() => { tb.AppendText(e.Data + Environment.NewLine); }));
    }

    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (proc != null) proc.Kill();
        proc.Dispose();
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: код проверил - не работает. точнее работает точно так же как и три предыдущих примера.  Filename = python, Arguments = C:\\test.py. Можно взять любой пайтоновский скрипт, типа `import time while True: print("Hello") time.sleep(3)`  - будем выводить Hello через каждые три секунды - можете попробовать самостоятельно - в форме ничего выводиться не будет. возможно это проблема python, но в cmd он выводит, значит в чем проблема забрать этот потом и вывести в форму.

Comment: @Gypnofrog беру свои слова обратно, с питоном действительно какая-то хрень, такое впечатление что он пишет не в stdout, а куда-то еще и только в конце сбрасывает в stdout. Надо копнуть параметры самого python.exe, может какими-то ключами можно заставить его работать как обычное консольное приложение

Comment: @Gypnofrog нашел проблему, но не нашел лекарство. Когда вы запускаете скрипт, то сначала стартует процесс python.exe, который, вероятно, используется для преднастройки или чего-то подобного, а сам скрипт исполняет другой процесс python.exe, который запускается первым процессом. Редирект у нас стоит для первого процесса, а вывод пишет второй.

Comment: В этом изначально и была проблема, если бы нужно было запустить что-то помимо пайтона, я бы не обратился за помощью. К сожалению, за прошедшие две недели решение найти пока не удалось. в интернете тоже ничего путного на этот счёт нет. поэтому предлагаю найти решение вместе, думаю еще ни раз пригодится

Comment: @Gypnofrog пока ни чего умнее перенапрвления вывода python в файл с помощью его собственных аргументов и периодического перечитывания этого файла ничего не накопал.

Comment: почти удалось заставить c# понимать то, что пишет python. добавил в аргументах индекс -u при запуске python. чтение из потока работает, но странным образом читаются не все строки. не понимаю по какому принципу часть читается, а часть нет. Ваша идея интересна, не совсем понимаю как заставить c# читать документ в который постоянно пишет python, подскажете?

Comment: @Gypnofrog у меня с ключом `-u` не сработало совсем, на том примере скрипта, который вы дали. О python я, по большому счету, знаю что он есть и на нем тоже можно писать код. По поводу файла - можно попробовать предварительно открыть файл на чтение с параметрами шаринга, разрешающими запись другим программам и его указать в ключах python для редиректа. Ну и слушать изменения файла каким-нибудь FileSystemWatcher-ом. Но пока нет времени попробовать.

Comment: в итоге пришлось приложение python и всё заработало, огромное спасибо за консультацию!

Comment: @Gypnofrog я не совсем понял, что именно вы сделали, чтобы заработало. Думаю стоит дополнить ответ или даже написать отдельный, а то пока он вроде как не совсем отвечает на вопрос как

Comment: как я писал ранее, я запустил python с параметром -u, что позволило отключить буферизацию вывода, но в таком случае приходится выбирать - либо python пишет в лог-файл, либо в stream. я нашел такое решение - python передает выходные данные в stream командой print, а c# читает их, обрабатывает и пишет в лог-файл. выглядит кривовато, но другого решения на протяжении трёх недель мне найти не удалось, похоже, что это единственный способ подружить python и c#

Comment: @Gypnofrog напишите в отдельном ответе что у вас в итоге получилось. Интересно же, вдруг когда самому понадобится =) Галочку можно будет переставить, а на мой ответ просто сослаться, как на доп. материал, чтобы не дублировать много кода.